# If ++a return lvalue then why &(++a) show compile error?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, rvalue, lvalue

I have heard that `++a` returns l-value in c wheres `a++` returns r-value in c.
Since `++a` return l-value then why &(++a) throws complilation error?

Here's a link: [Why is ++x a lvalue and x++ a rvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802859/why-is-x-a-lvalue-and-x-a-rvalue/50802921)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=1,*p;
    p=&(++a);
    printf("%d",p);
}
```

Error message:

```
guess.c: In function ‘main’:
guess.c:6:4: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
  p=&(++a);
```

Comment: You're wrong: `++a` does not return an lvalue in C — so you're starting from a false premise, leading to a false conclusion.  Note that your linked question is explicitly tagged [tag:c++] and [tag:c++11] — what applies in C++, especially in C++11 or later, very often does not apply to C, not even C11 or C17 (C18).

Comment: Why do you think a temporary can be a lvalue?

Comment: @Bathsheba it is not useful at all because if you google the error message along with the word "increment" you'll find out that it is a duplicate. That, coupled with a false premise without sources to it and there is not much left to salvage.

Comment: @Bathsheba that along with the error message rather explicitly spelling out that that which is given to `&` is, in fact, not an lvalue.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Well done; you've established yourself as being more experienced than the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up C with C++. In C++, you can indeed do that. In C, `++a` just gives you the new value of `a` (an rvalue in C++ terms), and you can't take the address of that.

And of course, your print should be `printf("%d\n", *p);`, not `printf("%d\n",p);` (or `printf("%p\n", (void *)p);`, if you want to print the address of `a`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil it would make no sense to define ++a returning a lvalue. It returns a temporary. Even in C++ naming convention a temporary can't be a lvalue.

Comment: @user6556709: It would make sense. Whether it produces a temporary is irrelevant. The C standard **could** say it produces (not returns; this is not a function call) an lvalue, and there is no technical impediment to implementing that. It simply does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is not irrelevant that the result is a temporary. It defines its life-time. Making it a lvalue would have some interesting impacts on the way how life-time is handled.

Comment: @user6556709 Why would it impact lifetime to "expose" (because in C it doesn't return) the actual item incremented? C++ seems to be quite happy? I'm just after detail? OK, you can say C++ is not C, but that doesn't actually explain anything.

Comment: @user6556709: First, you are wrong that the result of `++` is a temporary. The only temporary objects in C are non-lvalue expressions with structure or union type (C 2018 6.2.4. 8), and `++` is only defined for real or pointer types (6.5.3.1 1). Second, even if it were a temporary, that would be irrelevant because we are not discussing what the C standard **does** say but what the C standard **would** say if it were changed so the result of `++` were an lvalue. In that case, it would not be a temporary.

Comment: @user6556709: As evidence this would be a technically feasible change to the C standard and would not fundamentally break the language, observe it can be implemented with `#define pp(x) (*(++(x), &(x)))`. With this definition, `pp` acts as the hypothetical `++` would: `pp(x)` applies `++` to `x` and produces an lvalue for `x`. Therefore, this is a possible operation in C, and the fact that `++` is not specified that way is only a matter of choice, not of technical necessity.

Comment: @GemTaylor: Sorry, I tagged that comment wrong; it was for user6556709. `int x; (x = 1) = 2;` is not correct C; assignment does not produce an lvalue.

Comment: @user6556709: It occurs to me you may have thought the lvalue to be produced would be that of some temporary object. It would not. The idea is that `++a` would return an lvalue for `a`. There would be no temporary object.